# RuntimeError: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!

Tags: command-line

Please help me solving this issue.I am working on odroid-c1 board and started with gpio programming and my code is:

```
import time  
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
LED = 22  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  
GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)  
GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)  
while True:  
    GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH)  
    time.sleep(0.5)  
    GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)  
    time.sleep(0.5)   
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I have installed gpio libraries using these commands:

```
$ tar zxvf RPi.GPIO-0.5.6.tar.gz
$ cd RPi.GPIO-0.5.6
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

and when i tried to run the program i am getting this error:

```
$ odroid@odroid:~$ sudo python blinky.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "blinky.py", line 2, in   
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 23, in   
    from RPi._GPIO import *  
RuntimeError: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RPi.GPIO module only works on a Raspberry Pi. You can't use it on a odroid-c1 board.

Comment: then which module will work on odroid-c1 for programming with gpio's

Answer (score 2):

Use the adequate GPIO library: https://github.com/swkim01/RPi.GPIO-OdroidC1

Comment: @amc This answer might not be written in a perfect way, but it attempts to answer the question by saying "use the linked `RPi.GPIO-OdroidC1` module instead of the `RPi.GPIO` module" as far as I can tell. Please rethink your decision on this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

wiringPi module will work for odroid-c1

Comment: @amc This answer might not be written in a perfect way, but it attempts to answer the question by saying "use the `wiringPi` module instead of the `RPi.GPIO` module" as far as I can tell. It has also been written by the OP themselves. Please rethink your decision on this post. Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander ok, but it still needs to add the necessary info to actually do that.